# Attempting to scroll a MapView during UITesting in Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, xcode-ui-testing

Simply put, I wish to have an automated test as part of my UI test suite that can scroll the map. I am not concerned about the location, I just need to move it from its original position.

### Why?

Two reasons:

1. The UI updates once the user interacts with the map. I wish to validate these changes
2. While I can easily verify this on a device, I also want to include automated screenshots via fastlane. Having a test perform this makes that possible

### What have I tested so far?

I found the following from a related issue and tested without success:

```
let map = app.maps.element
let start = map.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 200,
                                                          dy: 200))
let end = map.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 250,
                                                        dy: 250))
start.press(forDuration: 0.01, thenDragTo: end)
```

I can confirm that the `map` element is correctly set and contains the expected information.
I can also confirm that the coordinates I am using fall within the bounds of the map on the screen. I have also tested with a wide range of other values just in case.

I'm not concerned about how it is moved, or where it is moved to. All I need is to replicate a user moving the map by 1 point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coordinate(withNormalizedOffset:)` works a bit differently. The Vektor is multiplied to the size of your object.

From Apple's docs:

> The coordinate’s screen point is computed by adding normalizedOffset
>   multiplied by the size of the element’s frame to the origin of the
>   element’s frame.

That means that if you want to start dragging an the center of your map and then drag the map a bit you have to use it like this:

```
let map = app.maps.element
let start = map.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.5))
let end = map.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.6, dy: 0.6))
start.press(forDuration: 0.01, thenDragTo: end)
```

This puts the start coordinate at `0.5 * map.frame.width` and `0.5 * map.frame.height` and the end coordinate at `0.6 * map.frame.width` and `0.6 * map.frame.height`

When you run the UITest with this you'll see that it drags the map.

With your parameters it puts the start coordinate at `200 * map.frame.width` and `200 * map.frame.height` which is waaaay outside the screen so no dragging occurs.